# ElasticSearch field mapping

Tags: java, node.js, elasticsearch

In mt node app i am using Elastic-search as back-end. In that i have created an "Template" using the following query.

```
{

                "template" : "*",
                "settings" : {
                    "index.number_of_shards" : 3,
                    "index.number_of_replicas" : 1
                },
                "mappings" : {
                    "_default_" : { 
                        "_source" : { "enabled" : true,
                                      "compress" : true },
                        "_all" : { "enabled" : false },             
                        "properties" : {
                            "xx": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
                            "yy": { "type": "integer", "index": "not_analyzed" },
                            "zz": { "type": "integer", "index": "not_analyzed" },
                            "aa": { "type": "integer", "index": "not_analyzed" },
                            "locaiton": { "type": "geo_point", "index": "not_analyzed" } 
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
```

I have created an index name "`Temp`" so the above template will apply for that. Its working fine. But i want the filed name to be exact as the mapping:

Consider my data is as follows:

```
curl -XPOST "192.168.1.107:9200/temp/place" -d'{ "xx" : "asdfg",
"yy":34,
"zz":67,
"aa":78,
"locaiton":'78.80, 10.89' }'
```

It working:

But consider:

```
curl -XPOST "192.168.1.107:9200/temp/place" -d'{ "xx" : "asdfg",
"yyyyyyyyyy":34,------------------------> changing the field name is also accepting.
"zz":67,
"aa":78,
"locaiton":'78.80, 10.89' }'
```

I want an error message here. Is it possible in Elasticsearch. Please share your ideas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible , i found the solution:

While creating index-template set dynamic property to strict:

```
{

                    "template" : "*",
                    "settings" : {
                        "index.number_of_shards" : 3,
                        "index.number_of_replicas" : 1
                    },
                    "mappings" : {
                        "_default_" : { 
                            "_source" : { "enabled" : true,
                                          "compress" : true },
                            "_all" : { "enabled" : false },
                            "dynamic":"strict",
                            "properties" : {
                                "xx": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
                                "yy": { "type": "integer", "index": "not_analyzed" },
                                "zz": { "type": "integer", "index": "not_analyzed" },
                                "aa": { "type": "integer", "index": "not_analyzed" },
                                "locaiton": { "type": "geo_point", "index": "not_analyzed" } 
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
```